# Tomcat port open but app won't load

Tags: tomcat, tcp, apache2, port

I would like tomcat to run in both ports, 8080 and 9000. Port 8080 works perfectly but that is not the case for port 9000.

Port 9000 is open and listening:

```
$ ufw status
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere 
9000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I can connect to the port and get the index page

```
$ wget mydomain:9000
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1887 (1.8K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[=========================================>] 1,887       --.-K/s   in 0s
```

I have added a connector into the con/server.xml in tomcat

```
<Connector port="9000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
redirectPort="8443" />
```

But when I open the browser and type the address "mydomain:9000" the app is never loaded. It doesn't show any error, it just hangs there. I have checked the logs but no error is shown. I have no idea what the problem could be.Apache2 is running in port 80, but I am not sure if that is somehow related to the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Is the browser being run from the same machine where `wget` was working? Apache (httpd) is not the problem, here, unless you have it bound to port 9000 and Tomcat can't bind to that. Do you have an errors in `logs/catalina.out` when you launch Tomcat?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Apache is bound to port 80. After restarting tomcat, I open mydomain.com:9000 in the browser. Index. html is never shown but nothing is written to     catalina.out.  I connect to the server with ssh and then run     wget. The browser runs in my local machine (from where the     ssh is run).

Comment: Does DNS resolve properly for `mydomain` from the machine where the browser is running? What about running `wget` (or similar) from your local machine?

Comment: If I run `wget` from the local machine the connection times out ! Does that mean the port is not really open ? I have added the rule  `ufw allow 53/tcp` to the firewall, is there something else that should be added ?

Comment: sorry, I meant `ufw allow 9000/tcp`

Comment: Check firewalls on both machines. Also make sure that `nslookup mydomain` works from the browser/wget machine that times out. You may have to fully-qualify the domain name or use the IP address instead.

Comment: You were right ! There was another firewall blocking the connections. Once the port was open there, everything started working. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your firewalls allow communication between the client and server on that port (in both directions -- firewalls can black data in either direction or both).

Comment: Hi. That was exactly the problem. A second firewall was blocking all connections. Thank you for the help !